# Sort dataframe on date and variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to sort the below dataframe based on date and Variable consist in the same column.

DF

```
Date            Value
2019-01-01      445
AER_ST          220
BER_TT          225
2019-01-02      100
AER_ST          75
BER_TT          25
```

I want the `DF` in below mentioned format with latest date descending order.

DF2

```
Date              Value
2019-01-02        100
AER_ST            75
BER_TT            25
2019-01-01        445
AER_ST            220
BER_TT            225
```

I have tried below mentioned method.

```
DF$new<-ifelse(Output$Date=='AER_ST',1,
                    ifelse(Output$Date=='BER_TT',2,0))

DF2<-arrange(DF, desc(Date), desc(new))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possibility via Base R can be to split based on dates, order, rearrange the list and `rbind`, i.e.

```
l1 <- split(df, cumsum(!is.na(as.Date(df$Date, '%Y-%m-%d'))))
i1 <- order(as.Date(sapply(l1, function(i) i$Date[1]), '%Y-%m-%d'), decreasing = TRUE)
do.call(rbind, l1[i1])
```

which gives,

> ```
>           Date Value
> 2.4 2019-01-02   100
> 2.5     AER_ST    75
> 2.6     BER_TT    25
> 1.1 2019-01-01   445
> 1.2     AER_ST   220
> 1.3     BER_TT   225
> ```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to convert `Date` column to actual Dates so that the text would be converted to `NA` and only the actual dates would remain. Now we can `fill` those `NA`s with the previous `Date` values and `arrange` these dates in descending order.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date1 = as.Date(Date)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(Date1) %>%
  arrange(desc(Date1)) %>%
  select(-Date1)


#        Date Value
#1 2019-01-02   100
#2     AER_ST    75
#3     BER_TT    25
#4 2019-01-01   445
#5     AER_ST   220
#6     BER_TT   225
```

Comment: Thanks :) Is it possible if for some date if `BER_TT` row is missing than show that row as well in `Final` dataframe with `0` value.??